# How do I calculate the total distance traveled with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, 2dsphere

I need to calculate the total distance traveled between a collection of points. They all have a timestamp to get them in the right order. I'm only allowed to use MongoDB.

Sample collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596cd354241aa3174056fb98"),
    "spelerID" : 1,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-02-01T19:00:00.000Z"),
    "coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            4.29870386367084, 
            50.8357637566422
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596cd354241aa3174056fbb4"),
    "spelerID" : 1,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-02-01T19:00:01.000Z"),
    "coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            4.29868458167181, 
            50.8357575419868
        ]
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596cd354241aa3174056fbce"),
    "spelerID" : 1,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-02-01T19:00:02.000Z"),
    "coordinates" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            4.29867536067721, 
            50.8357376028214
        ]
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to calculate the distance between those points in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can performance the distance between two points by using $near or $geoNear.

*Returns documents in order of proximity to a specified point, from the nearest to farthest. geoNear requires a geospatial index.*
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/

In your case I don't think this will resolve the issue since you want to perform multiple distance calculation between multiple points.

MongoDB can be instruct to create very complex algorithm by using **MapReduce**. Even if I'm not expert in GIS application you could try to create a MapReduce routine with a Function that compute the distance between multiple points ordered as you like.

[MongoDB - MapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)

This link can help you to write a JS function to be used in Map Reduce:
[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula?rq=1)

Good Luck!